# Sending simultaneous NSURLConnection requests

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, http

Is it possible to make simultaneously two requests in parallel to the same server using NSURLConnection?

I'm trying to do it, and it looks like the second request do not start until the first one finishes.

Comment: The problem is not making two NSURLConnection requests in parallel, but two NSURConnection requests in parallel to the same target domain.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the sync version of NSURLConnection

```
+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error
```

you need to start two threads to get the behavior you want, you can do this my moving the download in a own method and call this over:

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg
```

The other way would be to use Asynchronously version of NSURLConnection, [see docu](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html).

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two NSURLConnection objects.

Answer (score 1):

The second request seems to be waiting the first one if cookies exist.
I believe it's done to send actual cookies in the second request because they can be modified in the response for the first request.

You can turn handling of cookies off by setting a property HTTPShouldHandleCookies to NO.